# Chrome Extension - Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension that requires message passing between the background script and content script. However, I'm encountering an error message: "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist." I have followed the official Chrome Extension documentation and other resources, but I'm unable to resolve this issue. thanks in advance:

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        id: "copyAccessToken",
        title: "Copy Access Token",
        contexts: ["all"],
    });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
    if (info.menuItemId === "copyAccessToken") {
        const originTabId = tab.id;
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, (tabs) => {
            const destinationTabId = tabs[0].id;

            // Inject the content script into the destination tab
            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: { tabId: destinationTabId },
                files: ["content.js"],
            }, () => {
                // Once the content script is injected, send a message to copy the access token
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(destinationTabId, {
                    action: "copyAccessToken",
                    originTabId,
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.action === "copyAccessToken") {
        const accessToken = sessionStorage.getItem("gcdm-accessToken");
        if (accessToken !== null) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("gcdm-accessToken", accessToken);
            sendResponse({ success: true });
        } else {
            sendResponse({ success: false });
        }
    }
});
```

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const copyForm = document.getElementById("copyForm");
    const originTabSelect = document.getElementById("originTab");
    const destinationTabSelect = document.getElementById("destinationTab");
    const messageDiv = document.getElementById("message");

    // Fetch and populate the tab options
    chrome.tabs.query({}, (tabs) => {
        tabs.forEach((tab) => {
            const option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = tab.id;
            option.textContent = tab.title;
            originTabSelect.appendChild(option);
            destinationTabSelect.appendChild(option.cloneNode(true));
        });
    });

    copyForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const originTabId = originTabSelect.value;
        const destinationTabId = destinationTabSelect.value;

        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
            { action: "copyAccessToken", originTabId, destinationTabId },
            (response) => {
                if (response && response.success) {
                    messageDiv.textContent = "Access token copied successfully.";
                } else {
                    messageDiv.textContent =
                        "Failed to copy access token. Make sure the origin tab has a valid access token.";
                }
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.sendMessage (with a tab id) instead of chrome.runtime.sendMessage in popup.